# How can I submit custom feature extraction methods to music21?

Tags: python, machine-learning, music21

I'm trying to figure out if I'm able to submit any of my custom music21 feature extraction methods to music21.

for my undergraduate research position at Ohio State, I'm have to create custom methods to extract necessary features for my model. I had to create all of these methods because I wasn't able to find them in the music21 documentation. Some of these methods could be important and I feel like they could be useful for other people who are using music21 to extract music features.

Comment: Welcome to SO, which is about *specific coding* questions; your question is arguably off-topic, please do take some time to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). BTW, at the bottom of the [music21 homepage](http://web.mit.edu/music21/), there are instructions on how to contribute...

Comment: The link at the bottom of music21 is broken. I should've specified that in my post.

Comment: The web link is not necessary, there is an *email* address there of the principal investigator, where all contributors are requested to contact. And again, the fact does not make the question on-topic here - please see #7 in the list of the link provided in my previous comment